# NullPointerException using the VisualVM launcher

Tags: linux, java, eclipse

I'm running Arch. I installed eclipse-java from the AUR and later installed visualvm from there too. After setting up the visualvm launcher, and creating a run configuration using it, I still get a NullPointerException, although the paths are correct. I'm running OpenJDK 8 and visualvm is located at `/usr/bin/visualvm` (which I entered in the preferences). Still it produces this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Test Profiling".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

After I triple checked the paths (the JDK Home is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/`, VisualVM Executable is set to `/usr/bin/visualvm`) I tried creating symlinks in `jdk/bin` to the visualvm executable, still it throws this exception.

Any information on how to fix this? Every setup tutorial I saw only contained setting the paths to the right locations (which I did).

Answer (score 2):

The eclipse plugin is parsing the output of "java -version" and checks for "java version" to find out the version. OpenJDK 8 is reporting "openjdk version" and thus the parsing fails.
You need to either recompile the plugin from [here](https://java.net/projects/visualvm/sources/svn/show/trunk/integrations/eclipse) or use the Oracle JDK.